Including URLs in an environment.yml for conda
I am working on creating a reproducible workflow for setting up a personal conda environment, and I'm using an environment.yml for the dependencies. One of the libraries need to be installed from a specific URL/channel, but I'm not sure what the proper syntax is to handle URLs in the file.
Simplified example:
# Add this to the channels
conda config --add channels https://software.repos.intel.com/python/conda/

In environment.yml, we then have
name: test
channels:
 - conda-forge
dependencies:
 - python=3.10
 - pip
 - https://software.repos.intel.com/python/conda/::intelpython3_core
 - conda-forge::pandas

Here I'm using the channel::library syntax as per the documentation, which works for the conda-forge::pandas example. But running conda env create --file environment.yml gives the following error:
UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for channel python/conda <https://conda.anaconda.org/python/conda>

I've tried putting quotes around it but that gives another error. Is there a way to specify the channel properly when it's a URL?
